# Setting Up Composer For Terminal

Tags: terminal

I was wondering on the newest version of Terminal and Os X how I could install the "Composer" code inside of Terminal because the tutorial I am following needs it.

If anyone could give me the code for Terminal to install this, that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should have curl on your os x install:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Then, you have to move it into /usr/local/bin if you want to use it globally:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

and change permissions to let normal user execute composer:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: When I type the first line it says Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'There is no version of Composer available for your PHP version (5.5.27)' in -:456
Stack trace:

Comment: Can you update your 5.5 installation to the newest?
They could stop supporting old 5.5.x versions.

Comment: How did you install php?
Easiest option is to run:
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5

Comment: After I run your code it still says Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'There is no version of Composer available for your PHP version (5.5.27)' in -:456
Stack trace: @Mateusz Sip